# Why is URL response Null?

Tags: android, httpurlconnection

I have a simple class JSONParse which I want return response of any URL.
I want a separate class where I can directly get the response of any URL. 
I have tried it but I get Null instead of json response :(

This is my Class

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.util.Log;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;

public class JSONParser extends AsyncTask<String , Void ,String> {
    private String server_response;
    Activity activity;
    private static  String response;

    public String getResponse(Activity activity, String url){
        this.activity = activity;
        this.execute(url);
        return response;
    }
    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... strings) {
        URL url;
        HttpURLConnection urlConnection = null;

        try {
            url = new URL(strings[0]);
            urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();

            int responseCode = urlConnection.getResponseCode();

            if(responseCode == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK){
                server_response = readStream(urlConnection.getInputStream());
                Log.v("CatalogClient", server_response);
            }

        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String s) {
        super.onPostExecute(s);
        response = s;
    }

    private String readStream(InputStream in) {
        BufferedReader reader = null;
        StringBuffer response = new StringBuffer();
        try {
            reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in));
            String line = "";
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                response.append(line);
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            if (reader != null) {
                try {
                    reader.close();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
        return response.toString();
    }
}
```

This is Where I'm Calling this method

```
        String url = "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/1";
        String response = new JSONParser().getResponse(url);
        Log.d(TAG, "Response is :"+response);
```

I'm getting Null response in here but I'm getting correct response in the class JSONParse.
Does anybody know what happened here :(

Comment: you returning null in doInBackground() you should return server_response which is has actual json data

Comment: @AnilUgale, I'm still getting null response

Comment: because you have to wait for complete onPostExecute() method and then access the response.in your code you direct call getResponse(). it give the null because. server call is not completed when you call getResponse()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Calling AsyncTask:

```
String url = "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/1";
new JSONParser(url).execute();
```

And the whole AsyncTask logic:

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.util.Log;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;

public class JSONParser extends AsyncTask<String , Void ,String> {
    private String server_response;
    private static  String response;
    private String serverUrl = url;

    public void JSONParser(String url){
        this.serverUrl = url;
    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... strings) {
        URL url;
        HttpURLConnection urlConnection = null;

        try {
            url = new URL(serverUrl);
            urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();

            int responseCode = urlConnection.getResponseCode();

            if(responseCode == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK){
                server_response = readStream(urlConnection.getInputStream());
                Log.v("CatalogClient", server_response);
                return server_response;
            }

        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String s) {
        response = s;
        Log.d(TAG, "Response is :"+response);
    }

    private String readStream(InputStream in) {
        BufferedReader reader = null;
        StringBuffer response = new StringBuffer();
        try {
            reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in));
            String line = "";
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                response.append(line);
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            if (reader != null) {
                try {
                    reader.close();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
        return response.toString();
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm still getting null response buddy

Comment: @SunnyBhadana I edited my answer, should work now. The AsyncTask is asynchronous operation, so you could get the result and working with UI only in onPostExecute method.

Comment: Ok if I done it. How can I get response on my MainActivity? because now it is not returning anything and I want response in MainActivity

Comment: Fo example, make the UI stuff in the onPostExecute method and put the whole AsyncTask in your Activity. Or pass into constructor of AsyncTask the listener interface and in the onPostExecute call the method of this interface with the result.

Answer (score 0):

You are returning null in doInBackground that is why your onPostExecute is or will be null. Set return to your response which in your case will be as follows:

```
@Override
protected String doInBackground(String... strings) {
    URL url;
    HttpURLConnection urlConnection = null;

    try {
        url = new URL(strings[0]);
        urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();

        int responseCode = urlConnection.getResponseCode();

        if(responseCode == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK){
            server_response = readStream(urlConnection.getInputStream());
            Log.v("CatalogClient", server_response);
        }

    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return server_response;
}
```